# How to scan IP in the same network in iOS?

Tags: ios, networking, ip

I want to get all the active IP in local network in a efficient way. I tried to ping the 255 broadcast address. But some OS like Windows and Android do not response to the broadcast packet. To ping every IP from 1 to 255 will take several minutes. It's too slow. Please give some advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used multithread to ping from 1 to 255, it saves much time.